# Custom textfield on antd Select Component

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, drop-down-menu, antd, textinput

I want to give the user ability to add custom text if the choice they deam fit is not among those shown in the Select option. I have managed to create the custom textfield however getting the user input and seting it as the value for the select component is becoming a pain(sounds like something easy to do but for some reason its not woking)
here is my implememntation

```
  const [selectedpurpose, setSelectedPurpose] = useState<string>("");// selected value of the select component
  const [customOption, setCustomOption] = useState<string>("");//custom userinput
  
   const [dropoptions, setDropOptions] = useState([
{ value: "General Meeting", label: "General Meeting" },
{ value: "Consultation Meeting", label: "Consultation Meeting" },
{ value: "AdCampaign Meeting", label: "Ad Campaign Meeting" },
{ value: "Marketing Meeting", label: "Marketing Meeting" },
 ]);//select options

 // function to recored custom user input
 const handleAddOption = () => {
  if (customOption) {
  const newOption = { value: customOption, label: customOption };
  setDropOptions([newOption, ...dropoptions]);
  setSelectedPurpose(customOption);
  setCustomOption("");
 }
 };
    
   //my form
   <Form.Item
          name="purpose"
          label="Purpose of Visit"
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: "Please select Purpose of Visit!",
            },
          ]}
        >
          <Select
            defaultActiveFirstOption={false}
            value={selectedpurpose}
            onChange={(e) => {
              if (customOption) {
                setSelectedPurpose(customOption);
              }else{
                setSelectedPurpose(e)
              }
            }}
            dropdownRender={(menu) => (
              <div>
                {menu}
                <div
                  style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    flexWrap: "nowrap",
                    padding: 8,
                  }}
                >
                  <Input
                    style={{ flex: "auto" }}
                    maxLength={20}
                    value={customOption}
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      if (e.target.value.length > 20) {
                        // if user has reached the maximum length
                        // show a message or change the color of the input to indicate the limit has been reached
                        // for example:
                        openNotificationWithIcon(
                          "error",
                          "Warning",
                          "Maximum length reached!"
                        );
                      } else {
                        setCustomOption(e.target.value);
                      }
                    }}
                    onKeyDown={(e) => {
                      if (e.key === "Enter") {
                        handleAddOption();
                      }
                    }}
                  />
                  <Button
                    type="link"
                    onClick={handleAddOption}
                    style={{ flex: "none", padding: "0px 4px" }}
                  >
                    Add
                  </Button>
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
          >
            {dropoptions.map((option) => (
              <Option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
                {option.label}
              </Option>
            ))}
          </Select>
        </Form.Item>
```

What am I doing wrong, as per my code clicking add button button and pressing enter should add the new value to the options array as well as select the user input as the value of the select component but as of now it will only add it to the options array and ignores setting it as the select value
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
 try this one   
    
     import React from "react";
        import "./styles.css";
        import Select, { components } from "react-select";
        
        const CustomInput = (props) => {
          const { maxLength } = props.selectProps;
          const inputProps = { ...props, maxLength };
        
          return <components.Input {...inputProps} />;
        };
        
        const App = () => {
          const options = [
            { label: "Option 1", value: 1 },
            { label: "Option 2", value: 2 },
            { label: "Option 3", value: 3 }
          ];
        
          return (
            <Select
              options={options}
              components={{ Input: CustomInput }}
              maxLength="4"
            />
          );
        };
        
        export default App;
```